# Kendo UI Grid Export to excel with extra info in the file?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have an application which uses Kendo UI grid. The excel export features works fine. Now, I added some extra controls on the page. User can select some values, and then click 'refresh' button to update the data source of the grid. So that the grid won't load too much data all in once.

The question is: the export will export whatever on the screen (including all pages). When user opens the excel file, he/she won't know what parameters used to generate this.

For example, on the page, it has a date control, use select 1/1/2015, click refresh, grid shows all data for that date. When export, how the user know this selected date? It is not in the columns in grid.

What I want to have is an extra row at the top, which shows something like:

```
Date: 1/1/2015, Para2: value2, ...
```

Is this possible in current Kendo ui grid? or have to manipulate the excel file (which we want to avoid at any cost)?

Thanks

---

we can use mult-column feature of latest kendo to add one more row at the top and covers all existing columns, and use it for extra information.

```
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/multicolumnheaders
```

However, I need to dynamically change the title of this row, i.e. when user select a parameter from drop down list, I need to reflect the change in the title. This can be done by jQuery. The problem is Export of Kendo. The export seems using whatever the initial title is. i.e. if I change parameters to:

```
Date: 2/1/2015, Para2: value2, ...
```

jQuery changed the title in this multi-column row. But the export still has:

```
Date: 1/1/2015, Para2: value2, ...
```

Anyone knows how to fix this? Or, can't be done in current Kendo?

Thanks

Comment: I am looking for the same solution . Did you find solution for this ? I am looking for adding some rows at the bottom of the excel